# How to extract a string regular expression using java?

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to extract what ever is within the below tokens

```
${FNAME} ${LNAME} ${123}
```

> FNAME LNAME 123.

I tried the below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "{FNAME} ${LNAME} ${123}";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);


    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");

    }

}
```

Ended up wrongly. Beginner to reg expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lazy` quantifier `?` and capture group `()` like this.

**Regex:** `\$\{(.*?)\}`

**Replacement to do:** `\1` for first captured group.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oI3pB8/2)